# preg_match для строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

HTML:

```
<li> <span>Цена:</span><span class="amount" itemprop="price" content="26.9">26.9</span><span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="UAH">грн</span></li>
```

PHP:

```
$content = file_get_contents("https://enext.ua/catalog/avtomaty-serii-e-stand/modulnyy-avtomatichekiy-vyklyuchatel-e-mcb-stand-45-1-B1-1r-1a-v-4-5-ka/");
preg_match('#itemprop="price">(.*?)</span>#im', $content, $price);
```

Не могу получить цену, выдает ошибку

Подскажите как получить цену которая находится между тегами span с помощью функции preg_match

P.S. Цену видно только если авторизован на сайте.

Comment: Если когда скачиваете через `file_get_contents` нет, значит перед этим надо заставить ваш парсер авторизоваться на сайте и потом скачивать файл.

Comment: как быть в таком случае?

Comment: @verstala вы для начала выведите свой `$content` и посмотрите что там

Comment: @verstala сначала скриптом авторизовываться потом скачивать файл.

Comment: Цену я не вижу. что же делать?